# What is the smallest capacity microSD ever produced?

Tags: flash, sd

With the microSD (a.k.a TransFlash) physical dimensions being fixed, flash memory manufacturers compete to fit as much capacity to this as possible, so there are a lot of articles documenting breaking the record for the biggest capacity for this form-factor.

But what about the smallest capacity microSD? With all possible capacities being powers of two, it's pretty easy to search for them. There are not many results, though.

So, for the sizes under 1GB I have found some photographic evidence of existence of the following capacities: 512MB, 256MB, 128MB, 64MB and 32MB.

The smallest of them being this card:

[image: 32MB SanDisk TransFlash]

Pictures of the cards with capacities below 32MB are published by various Chinese memory manufacturers, however all of these images seem to be photoshopped, so they can not be considered as evidence of these cards being ever produced. Anyway, this is one of such pictures of a 1MB card (the smallest I could find):

[image: 1MB MRT3C microSD card]

Are there any non-power-of-two capacities of microSD/TransFlash cards? Is there a lower limit for the capacity in the specification? What other factors can limit the minimum capacity of such memory card? What is the smallest capacity that actually exists?

Comment: From memory (no pun intended -_-) I would say, that the smallest Micro-SD card there was, is 32MB.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SD_card) says 32MB.

Comment: When I first bought my "smart" phone (it was a Nokia 3650 with camera) back in 2004, it came with a 32 MB SD (not micro SD) card. That was probably the smallest capacity those days. A 256 MB card was too expensive and having one was no different than having a car :-) Memories...

Comment: I am a proud owner of an 8 MB SD (also not micro) card that came with grandfather's digital video camera. Still useful for testing a custom SD "driver" implementation. Edit: And looks like it's a genuine Panasonic card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MicroSD is a smaller extension of SD, and has the same limitations.

when SD was created, there was no official "minimum capacity" per the standard, but at the time, CompactFlash, SmartMedia, and Memory Stick were already at 16 MB or higher. At launch of the format, there were 32 MB cards available, with 8 MB being the smallest that were regularly produced (generally branded by digital camera makers as the "pack in" card with their camera.)

There may be smaller out there, but they would be oddball "custom" ones.

Similarly, by the time MicroSD was created (originally named "TransFlash" by SanDisk, it was compatible with SD needing just a passive adapter to work in SD card slots, SanDisk later released it to the SD Association and it became "microSD",) larger cards were common (128 MB was available at launch,) so at the time of TransFlash's launch, 32 MB was the smallest normally-produced card. I have seen a 16 MB card, though, apparently as the pack-in with a cell phone.

As for "non-power-of-two", absolutely! 200 GB and 400 GB were semi-common before 256 GB and 512 GB were achieved.

One other quirk of SD - it has three major generations, and each generation does have a "maximum possible size". The original SD (also sometimes called "SD-SC" for "SD Standard Capacity" tops out at 2 GB. (Although there were cards that "speak SDSC" available at 4 GB, very few devices know how to work with them.) Then came "SD High Capacity" or SD-HC. These were available from 4 GB to 32 GB. The current generation is "SD eXtended Capacity" or SD-XC. These support from "greater than 32 GB" to 2 TB; although no 2 TB cards are on the market yet. It is possible to create a lower-capacity card of the newer generation, so someone could make an 8 GB SD-XC card, but there's no reason to - the data side limitations mean that a system that recognizes SD-XC would also be able to handle the larger capacity just fine.

MicroSD has the same generations. And the Micro-to-full-size adapter doesn't change, it's just passing the pins through. So my original-from-2004 SanDisk **TransFlash** to SD card adapter works just fine with a 1 TB microSD-XC card.

The next generation has been announced and finalized "SD-UC" (SD Ultra Capacity) that supports from "over 2 TB" to 128 PB, but there are other standards such as SDExpress that are likely to take over.

*Devices* are completely backward compatible - the SD-XC slot in my Mac Studio can read 32 MB original-1999-launched SD card just fine.  But the *cards* are not. My ancient Canon digital camera can only take original SD-SC cards. If I put in a 4 GB SD-HC card, it won't read it. My Nintendo Wii can read SD-HC cards, but not SD-XC, so 32 GB is the biggest it can take. (Note: When the Wii launched, the *hardware* supported SD-HC, but the *software* did not. It was, however, compatible with the rare, not-officially-standard 4 GB SD-SC card. The Wii added SD-HC support with a software update.)

Lastly, there is one "variant" of SD/MicroSD worth talking about. For nearly all of SD's life, and even the vast majority of cards sold today, there are nine pins at the edge of the card. In 2011, an optional extra set of extra pins behind the main pins was added as the "Ultra High Speed II" optional standard, or "UHS-II". These cards can operate at up to 300 MB/s, while cards with only one set of pins top out at 170 MB/s. UHS-II cards are 100% compatible with non-UHS-II devices, though; they just operate at the slower speed.

While UHS-II was added after SD-XC was already the latest version, and the majority of UHS-II cards are SD-XC of 64 GB or larger; UHS-II is a backward compatible option. I have a UHS-II 32 GB SD-HC card. In non-UHS-II devices (Nintendo Wii for example) it tops out at 25 MB/s, but in a modern reader, it can get the full 300 MB/s.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any non-power-of-two capacities of microSD/TransFlash cards?

yes. Reported capacity is what the firmware on the card tells the host device, and it's any integer. It's what the vendor can print on the card as usable amount of memory.

Seeing that it makes sense to assume the physical amount of memory on a flash device is something like a power of two (or a low integer multiple of one), the amount of available memory will always be less than that – due to wear-levelling needing some percentage of storage, and most importantly, because any large flash memory does forward error correction.

I've personally not seen any SD card advertising below 32 MB (which is already a card that has less than the advertised amount of bytes, but you know, advertising). Might simply never made have sense, commercially, to produce such: there's a cost for the SD card controller die, that you have to have no matter how small your flash memory is, and then there's not infinitely many sizes of flash memory suitable for the available SD card controllers. A memory factory produces one size of memory at a time – and if your machine and process allow you to produce 32 MB flash memory, building smaller memory doesn't make for cheaper one. (Of course, smaller memories should have higher yield, but you can't reduce the cost of a sold memory arbitrarily – at some point, cutting (and losses due to cuts), testing, bonding, and shipping are simply more expensive than the wafer material.)

So, it's quite possible that aside from early prototypes and things-that-are-drastically-broken-memory, you will not find smaller sizes.